# How to re-request permissions in Facebook SDK 4.0

Tags: android, facebook

I got the `FacebookActivity` and unchecked the friends permission.
Now in the application i want to ask for it again so i tried doing:

```
 mLoginManager.registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
                new FacebookLoginCallback(this, pPermissions));
```

when in pPermissions i put `Arrays.asList("user_friends")`.

But now the `FacebookActivity` is disapearing without letting me choose the permissions and automatically rejects this permission.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by removing the app from the Facebook application.
Now everything works fine...
That was really wierd.