# Re-ask declined permissions in Facebook not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-facebook, facebook-permissions

Let's say user is prompt for permission A, B, C and denies B. Login will fail but when I try to perform login again, instead of showing the dialogue where I can accept or revoke permissions, shows the dialogue where the message "You've already authorized **app name**" is shown and the permission B remains denied.

I'm using this code to perform Facebook login:

**Setup code:**

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
...
if (mCallbackManager == null) {
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    mDeniedPermissions = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...));
}
```

**Login code:**

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        ...
        mDeniedPermissions = loginResult.getRecentlyDeniedPermissions();             
    }
    ...
});
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, mDeniedPermissions);
```

I've tried to ask for all permissions again, only for the revoked ones, performed `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()` to clear the session but nothing seems to work... 
Once revoked only using Facebook app or website to restore them again.
How can I solve this?

ps: this question is identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770536/how-to-re-ask-declined-permissions-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-android) but the solution doesn't work in my case, I've tried it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found the problem. I was using SDK 4.3.0. Now that I'm using 4.7.0 [**user2403096's** answer to **kyanro's** post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29775816/1423773) works.